# Mysql trigger update field on t2 on update t1 column

Tags: mysql

I've 2 tables (t1,t2) on my test db.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
`name` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`end_date` varchar(8) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t2` (
`date` varchar(8) NOT NULL
);
```

I'd like to create a trigger for update t2.date (with t1.end_date value) when update t1.end_date.
I've tried this way but with no success (Variable 'OLD' is not a variable component (can't be used as XXXX.variable_name)).

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_date BEFORE UPDATE ON t1 FOR EACH ROW
IF NOT (t1.NEW.end_date <=> t1.OLD.end_date) THEN
SET t2.OLD.date = t2.NEW.end_date;
END IF
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_date AFTER UPDATE ON t1 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   IF NOT (NEW.end_date <=> OLD.end_date) THEN
      update t2
      SET `date` = NEW.end_date;
   END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

#### And please don't use strings to store dates. Use the `date` data type!

Comment: Now I've no error message but if I update end_date my t2.date not updated.

Comment: Hmmm. Have you tried defining your trigger an `after update` trigger?

Comment: Yes, I copy exactly your code and I tried (UPDATE `t1` SET `end_date`='20120101') but t2.date is empty.

Comment: Of course it is empty. You are running an **update** query on `t2`. You have to have an entry to **update** it.